# Can the unicode character U+02B9 be produced using T1 or/and LGR encoding by pdfLatex?

Tags: pdftex, symbols, unicode

Is there a way to type the Unicode character U+02B9 in pdfLatex (command, macro, keyboard combination ...) without getting an error? Copy and paste the character does not help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\begin{document}  
    $(Xʹ)$, Eʹ,  This is Unicode character U+02B9: ʹ  
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above gives error. I know that there are some alternative characters, but different: smaller, thinner etc. This character is very well seen. Is there any way to type in pdfLaTeX this character or another very closed to this one?

Comment: This is the *prime* character. You just have to type a prime on your keyboard.

Comment: Actually, U+02B9 is `MODIFIER LETTER PRIME`, but if you need the PRIME character U+2032 something like `$\prime$` should do. Or, of course, switch to a Unicode capable TeX engine and a suitable font.

Comment: note the question as asked doesn't have a direct answer or has answer "no" pdftex fonts have at most 256 characters so never have a character in slot hex 02b9 (= 697)  . Actually as you mention LGR are you looking for Greek numeral sign? U+0374 is GREEK NUMERAL SIGN which is a character which normalises to U+02B9 this is `\textnumeralsigngreek` in the LGR setup for LaTeX

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes that I was looking for. I also found the \textdexiakeraia and \anwtonos but I noticed that \textnumeralsigngreek, \textdexiakeraia, \anwtonos, shift+; and ' all five produce the same output symbol in pdfLatex. This is not of course the case for LuaLatex and XeLatex. Any way I am fully satisfied with what you clarify and explain us here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+02B9 is MODIFIER LETTER PRIME and like all Modifier letters should be avoided. Like U+2032 PRIME it is full size so would need to be in a superscript.

`'` expands to `^{\prime}` so if you have documents with U+02B9 and removing them is inconvenient you can define it via

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02B9}{'}
```

---

U+02B9 has the same Unicode Normalisation as U+0374 GREEK NUMERAL SIGN which is set up with Unicode mapping in the greek inputenc mapping so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Eʹ
\end{document}
```

that uses

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0374}{\textnumeralsigngreek}       % ʹ \anwtonos
```

from `lgrenc.dfu` so you could add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02B9}{\textnumeralsigngreek}       % ʹ \anwtonos
```

if you are looking for this use.

Comment: @ David Carlisle I was looking for a slightly bigger and clearer symbol than this produced in pdfLatex output by using all five alternative input methods I mentioned in a previous comment. But this one is just fine. So everything is perfectly in place. I keep also the ideas for compatibility you explained above.